# How to set custom font family using CSS in Xamarin

Tags: css, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to set custom font family using CSS file in Xamarin forms project.
I placed the respective font in the android and ios project (Assets/Bodoni.ttf for android) and (Resources/Bodoni.tff for IOS)

and declared the class in the css file

```
.titleLabel {
    font-family: Bodoni;
    color: #960051;
}
```

The css file is well interpreted and my element (Label) contains the styleClass attribute with the value from above. The color property works well but the font family does not change.

Are there any other manipulations to do to integrate my custom font ?

Answer (score 0):

All CSS files in the shared project needs to target its BuildAction as EmbeddedResource.

As well any specific platform resource needs to have its BuildAction set as:

- iOS: BundleResource
- Android: AndroidResource

Your problem could be more related to the second paragraph, since the first one will throw an exception otherwise.

Comment: Yes my CSS file is in the shared project but i don't find how to set the BuildAction with microsoft visual studio.

Comment: Should be at properties. If you're on Mac OS, right-click the CSS file, then BuildAction.

Comment: I checked and the CSS file is well targeted as EmbeddedResource but the font family still doesn't work

Comment: How about the font files? Are those targeted to the right BuildAction?

EDIT: Do you actually have the fonts file?

Comment: They didn't target it, yes I have the fonts file in (app.Android/Assets/Bodoni.ttf for android) and (app.iOS/Resources/Bodoni.tff for IOS). When I try to target the the font files  as AndroidResource, this error appear : invalid resource directory name: MyApp.Mobile.App.Android\obj\Debug\res assets "res assets".

Comment: Currently my font files are targeting AndroidAsset in Android project